# output file directory using ghostscript

Tags: php, pdf, jpeg, ghostscript

I needed to parse a PDF file to images using php. I've done it with the help of ghostscript.  Here is the script:

```
$result = exec("gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOutputFile=%03d.jpeg $pdfname.pdf");
```

But I need the final images to be in another folder.  I've tried writing `-sOutputFile=/img/%03d` or `-sOutputFile=img/%03d` and in a lot of similar ways...but the program doesn't even work when I add these things.

Comment: Can you provide sample PDF and JPEG files which exhibit the white borders you describe?

Comment: Also, you are now asking a completely different question than the original. But your headline still describes the original question. -- This is not the way this website is supposed to work. **If you have a new question, ask a new question. Don't edit the existing question in this case.** Only edit existing questions to provide more info or required clarification.

Comment: ok, I'm going to create a new one. I'm sorry, i'm a new person here

Answer (score 3):

You need to create the `/img/` or `./img` directories **before** you run Ghostscript.

Ghostscript will not automatically create them if they don't exist.

Comment: Thanks, but that was not the problem. I've already solved it. It was because of the privacy, I changed it to 777 and everything staarted working correctly.